# Unresolved reference: LocationRequest for Android S (12)

Tags: android, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, android-12

Android 12 SDK seems to be stable now

[image]

if

```
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 30
```

then Play Services Location works fine

but if

```
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 31
```

then

[image]

p.s. Play Services Location version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
```

Comment: Added in SDK 31 : `android.location.LocationRequest` with `android.location.LocationRequest::Builder`?  Probably a long shot as `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest::create` is a completely different namespace and would require an import change to fail rather than a simple target/compile api change.

Answer (score 1):

`LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` is **deprecated**.

You have to use **`Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`** instead.

Here is the complete code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.Priority
```

and

```
val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
            interval = 5000
            fastestInterval = 1000
            priority = Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        }
```

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#public-static-final-int-priority_high_accuracy) for your reference.